# GoJS- Highlight GOJS diagram Links based on JSON

Tags: gojs

how can i highlight GoJS diagram links.

See The below picture I need show "Goods to ship activity" to "check if extra insurance is necessary activity" path Link Color should be Red color.

Reaming links Color should be in black color.

[image: Image file]

I am trying to understand Below example.
http://gojs.net/latest/extensions/BPMN.html

How can achieve this and what i need modify in the Input JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use simple data binding to control the color and/or strokeWidth and/or any other properties of any Link or Node, as discussed in http://gojs.net/latest/intro/dataBinding.html and demonstrated in nearly all of the samples, http://gojs.net/latest/samples.

Or you can use "highlighting", as discussed in http://gojs.net/latest/intro/highlighting.html and demonstrated in http://gojs.net/latest/samples/distances.html and http://gojs.net/latest/samples/friendWheel.html.  This too uses data binding, but the state is held by the **Part.isHighlighted** property rather than as some property on the data object in the model.